# How to trim unwanted text in PDF?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdftk

I can crop PDF (for example in Acrobat).

But text outside of the crop margin will still be maintained in the PDF (even though I don't see it in the viewable area).

I want to remove anything outside the crop margin. Is there a command line tool that can do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ghostscript can do that. Ghostscript is a command line tool which is available for all major operating systems.

The command which does it for Linux or Mac OS X:

```
gs -o cropped-and-removed.pdf \
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite          \
   -dUseCropBox               \
    in.pdf
```

The command for Windows:

```
gswin64c.exe -o cropped.pdf ^
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite        ^
   -dUseCropBox             ^
    in.pdf
```

Be sure to use a rather recent version of Ghostscript. Current is v9.16.